# Size DataGridviewRows to fill DataGridView

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

[image]

How can I adjust the columns horizontally so that the data fills the entire `DataGridView` and leaves no blank spaces to the left or right of the data?

So far I have used `WindowState = Maximized` and this doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry about that, I voted to close. That title is a bit **DETAILED** lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
```